# Linear Algebra: Verifying row space

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image]

I've found that basis for W is $ \{(1,1,0,0,0)^T \ $, $(0,0,1,-2,1)^T \} $ and basis required in part (b) to be $ \{(-1,1,0,0,0)^T \ $, $(0,0,2,1,0)^T \ $, $(0,0,-1,0,1)^T \ $}.
How can I verify the statement in part (c) and subsequently that in part (d)?

Comment: Same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986111/nullspace-orthogonal. Class fellows by chance?

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$(0,0,1,1,1)=(0,0,2,1,0)+(0,0,-1,0,1),$$

$$(-1,1,1,2,3)=(-1,1,0,0,0)+2(0,0,2,1,0)+3(0,0,-1,0,1),$$ and

$$(0,0,1,3,5)=3(0,0,2,1,0)+5(0,0,-1,0,1).$$

Is this true for all matrices? Well, note that elements of $W$ are perpendicular to the row space. So $W^{\perp}$ must be the row space.

Comment: Why did you combine rows 2 and 4 together into (-1, 1, 1, 3, 5)? Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Ups. It was a typo.